# Proving that inverse of the map is smooth

Tags: calculus

Suppose $f: U (\subset \mathbb R) \to L(\mathbb R^n, \mathbb R^m)$  is smooth.  For each $x\in U$,  $f(x)$ is a linear map from $\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^m$.  Assume for each $x\in U$, $f(x)$ is invertible.

I need to find whether $g: U\to L(\mathbb R^n, \mathbb R^m)$ given by  $g(x):= (f(x))^{-1}$  is a smooth function.

Definition of  smoothness: Let $f: \mathbb R\to L(\mathbb R^n, \mathbb R^m)$, define a net (indexed by $h$) in $L(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R^m)$ by $\left\{ \frac{f(t+h)-f(t)}{h}\right\}$.  If this net converges, we say first derivative of $f$ exists.   We denote the limit of this net  by $f'(t)$.  $f'$ is function from $\mathbb R \to L(\mathbb R^n, \mathbb R^m).$  Similar we can define $f''$.   If for every $n\geq 0$ $f^{(n)} $ exists, we say $f$ is smooth function.

Comment: Hint: the entries of an inverse matrix are rational functions  of the entries of the original matrix.

Answer (score 1):

First, if $f(x)$ is invertible we must have $n=m$.  It will suffice to show that inversion $M_n(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow M_n(\mathbb{R})$ is smooth.  Start with showing it on $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ by looking at an explicit formula for inversion.